# How to access HTML input FileUpload FileList object using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I want to access the value of the FileList object when I Choose files using HTML input FileUpload. When I `console.log` this FileList object, I can see this object in the console window but I am not able to access the values using AngularJS.

This is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" ng-model="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().myFunction()">

<p id="demo" ng-repeat="file in fileList">
  Name: {{file.name}} </br>
  Type: {{file.type}} </br>
</p>
{{fileList}}

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.myFunction = function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    $scope.fileList = x.files;
    console.log($scope.fileList); 
 };
}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directive has a pretty good API for working with files: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

The [usage section](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-usage) has some examples you can follow, including ones that work with multiple files.